The global wine drought that never was (title of news text that seems like truncated at first sight)
This is the title of a news text:

The global wine drought that never was
BBC - Wine shortage

The title caught my attention in that it sounded like truncated, but then I understood it was the past form of the verb "to be".
As far as I understand, it means "a drought that was never existed, experienced, seen, happened"
However, I wonder whether this is a literary use or can it be used used in daily life. For instance:

When he finally managed to buy the house, I saw happiness on his face that never was.


You certainly can use it in daily life but that would not be an example of it, because the happiness exists. But for example if he tried to buy a house then it fell through at the last minute, he could reflect on the happiness that never was.

1956 film The Man Who Never Was which shows various media and literary usage.

@WeatherVane - you beat me to it!

"a drought that was never existed, experienced, seen, happened" should be: a drought that never existed, was experienced, seen, happened"

The gist of the phrase is often that there was so much advance talk (punditry, letters to the editor, news coverage, online chat, etc etc) that the thing took on a life it never had, and now everybody seems to think it actually happened. Rather the opposite of the boy who cried wolf and Chicken Little.

“I saw happiness on his face that never was” would imply that his face never existed. As Dan’s answer says, the construction implies that the nonexistence is unexpected, but this would be too unexpected – people are not just expected to have faces, they have them by definition.

The [X] that never was is an idiom meaning some event or thing that people thought might happen, but did not actually happen.

an x or xes that never was or were is the use of the verb be to mean that never existed. It's an idiom, much used in journalism or formal writing.
Putting this in google will show many examples of it:
[asterisk] that never was.
The asterisk will show many examples, including:
The city that never was.
The project that never was.

"an x that never were"??

You misunderstood. "The __ that never was" is an idiom which means it had been expected to happen, or hoped for, but has never happened. You need all of those parts for it to make sense. So if it has in fact happened, it doesn't make sense to use that idiom.

It was extensively predicted; https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-20152231

Consider the book and movie The Man Who Never Was, about Operation Mincemeat: no one had expected Major William Martin to exist.
